# AppDomain exception is thrown

Tags: c#, appdomain, .net-assembly

I've found a lot of similar questions but couldn't find any solution.

I have following code:

```
    string file = "c:\\abc.dll";
    AppDomainSetup ads = new AppDomainSetup();
    ads.PrivateBinPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
    AppDomain ad2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AD2", null, ads);
    ProxyDomain proxy = (ProxyDomain)ad2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(ProxyDomain).Assembly.FullName, typeof(ProxyDomain).FullName); 

Assembly asm = proxy.GetAssembly(file); // exception File.IO assembly not found is thrown here after succesfully running the funktion GetAssembly.


  public class ProxyDomain : MarshalByRefObject
  {
     public Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyPath)
     {
        try
        {
           Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
           //...asm is initialized correctly, I can see everything with debugger
           return asm;
        }
        catch
        {
           return null;
        }
     }
  }
```

The most Interesting thing that then my GetAssembly funktion returns some other type, even my custom serializable class, everything is fine. Does someone know what I'm missing? Or It's just impossible to return loaded assembly to another domain?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to return an `Assembly` to the parent app domain? Typically, this would be avoided so the parent app domain does not have to load the assembly and it can be unloaded when the child app domain is unloaded.

Comment: It would help if you explained what you are trying to achieve with this ProxyDomain class. Why do you need a new AppDomain if you are going to return full assemblies to your main domain?

Comment: Well, I don't really need this assembly in my first appdomain. I have a lot of them in a folder and I had to find assemblies containing a special class attribute and return a list of dll names. I needed the second app domain because all assemblies which were loaded in the main appdomain can't be deleted until application restarts. I solved my problem, but would still know why it returns every other type and fails returning Assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine `File.IO` is sitting in your main application's bin directory? If so, your abc.dll will not know where to find it (unless your main application is also sitting in `C:\\`).

You need to do one of

1. `Bind` to the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and manually load the referenced dll
2. Change the `AppDomainSetup`'s base directory (which is one of the places `.NET` knows to look for dlls)
3. Install `File.IO` to the `GAC` (which is another one of the places `.NET` knows to look for dlls)
4. Add the location of `File.IO` to your AppDomainSetup's private probing path (which is another one of the places `.NET` will try to look for dlls).

Comment: File.IO is an exception type. abc.dll is in not in the same directory, there programm is executed. And as I said, every other return type works, just Assembly doesn't

Comment: The event didn't catch any events and basedircetory didn't change the thing

Comment: @VladL, there no "File.IO" exception type in .Net - all exception types have "Exception" in the name. Are you sure you copy-pasted exception type/text correctly?